# React Native : expected dynamic type 'string' but had type 'object'

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want my app to calculate dates. To do so, i input 3 dates and with a button, it should print them in an alert. When testing, i seem to have a bug. My button is :

```
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {{Alert.alert("Box", <calculator date {this.state.dateInit} />)}}}>
    <View style={styles.button}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Calculer</Text>
    </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

and calculator refers to

```
class calculator extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Text>Le CQE Initial etait le {String(this.props.date)}</Text>
      );
  }
}
```

I tried with this.props.date.toString() and String(this.props.date) both in the alert and the class and i still get an error

`TypeError: expected dynamic type string but had type object`

while toString() or String(...) should have translated it as string.

Thx for the help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a component in second argument of `alert` function

```
Alert.alert("Box", <calculator date {this.state.dateInit} />
```

but the second argument of `alert` should be string as described [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/alert.html)

Comment: yes, it is indeed right. I'll try and use react-navigation instead. I still have to understand how function work in react native ^^. Thanks !